# Trouble in chapter 7, "colors and styles" exercises of "Introduction to Wolfram Language"

Tags: documentation

In [chapter 7 "colors and styles"](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/07-colors-and-styles.html) of the "Elementary introduction to the Wolfram language", there are several exercises that involve printing a list of hues ranging from 0 to 1 in certain steps. Clicking "check answer" for any of these will cause the cell to hang indefinitely with "checking answer". Clicking the menu item Evaluation -> Abort current evaluation does nothing; neither does "remove from evaluation queue". Quitting Mathematica and then re-opening it seems to work. (I'm doing this on the notebook version of the book on my desktop).

For example, exercise 7.4 says

> "Make a list of colors with hues varying from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.02."

If you put the answer `Table[Hue[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.02}]`, and evaluate it, you can compare it to the "expected output" near the question and see that it matches. However, if you click "Check my solution", it will hang indefinitely.

I'm using Mathematica 13.1 on Debian 11. Interestingly, the same effect happens in Wolfram Cloud on this particular set of exercises, and it actually prevents me from evaluating any other cell.

Does this happen for anyone else?

Comment: Please include the code of at least one example that causes the problem.

Comment: sure I just included an example

Comment: Since this is not a question about Mathematica, I would suggest that you inform [support](https://support.wolfram.com/topic/mathematica). Only WRI would have access to their cloud infrastructure.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an issue with Mathematica or their cloud infra; my question is if this same behavior happens for anyone else. If it does not, then something is probably wrong with both my build of Mathematica and my own "instance" of wolfram cloud. But if it *does* happen for others, then we can conclude that it's probably an issue on their end (again with both Mathematica and their cloud infra)

Comment: It works as I expect it to in the desktop version on my laptop.

Comment: Whether or not this is a reasonable question for MSE, I also recommend contact with Tech Support. They might be able to replicate the issue and get it reported so the Cloud devels can have a look. Or so other devels can, should it be replicated in some desktop OS.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2617877).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been confirmed to be an issue. I reported it to Wolfram support, and got an email from support@wolfram.com that included the following:

> It does appear that there is an issue with checking the solution for EIWL exercise problem 7.4. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers based on the information you provided.